# Replace missing element in Puppeteer scraping results

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I use a script for recursively scraping data with Puppeteer. It works correctly but sometimes an element is missing in the page structure and at this point the script crashes.

I'd like to set a condition in case the element is missing. I tried several ways to add a condition but without success, like an if/else to check if element exists. There is an interesting thread here: [Continue on Null Value of Result (Nodejs, Puppeteer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47332699/continue-on-null-value-of-result-nodejs-puppeteer) but I can't replicate the solution in my Array.from structure.  Is there a way to achieve that? Any directions to start would be welcome.

Here is a the part of the script where i query elements:

```
  const results = await page.evaluate(() => 
          Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('article.main-wrap section'), value => ({
             name: value.querySelector('h1.title').innerText.trim(),
             frame: value.querySelector('ul li:nth-child(3)').innerText.trim(),
             // more elements to scrape
          }))
    );
```

when an expected element is missing in the page structure, I would like to replace the value in the key,value pair par something like "null". Maybe some kind of ternary syntax may be used in Array.from but I can't find anything.

Comment: Won't `if(!results.length) {}` do the job?

Comment: I'm afraid not because each page scrap is composed of about eight queries (name, frame, ...) and it's only one or two of them that sometimes are missing, not the whole array. If I understand your suggestion correctly, of course.

Comment: How about `frame : value.querySelector('ul li:nth-child(3)').innerText.trim() || 'NoFrame';`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I already tried a solution like that one but it still fails to evaluate with an error of "Cannot read property 'innerText' of null".

Comment: `value.querySelector('ul li:nth-child(3)') ? value.querySelector('ul li:nth-child(3)').innerText.trim() : 'foo'`?

Comment: Oh yes, that does the trick! It makes sense. First looking if the selector is there and filled before trying to get one of its properties (innerText or src or whatever), otherwise, print an alternative string. Very grateful!

Comment: Cool I'm adding that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator to check if `querySelector` returns a truthly value:

```js
const results = await page.evaluate(() => 
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('article.main-wrap section'), value => ({
        name: value.querySelector('h1.title') 
            ? value.querySelector('h1.title').innerText.trim()
            : 'falsy value',
        frame: value.querySelector('ul li:nth-child(3)') 
            ? value.querySelector('ul li:nth-child(3)').innerText.trim()
            : 'falsy value',
    }))
);
```